# clock() doesn't work properly on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the CPU time used by a function in my app. It works properly on iOS Simulator. but when I run it on my iPhone it just gives 0.

```
var t = clock()

myLongRunningFunction()

t = clock() - t
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11659289/1226963

Comment: You may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40195982/3541063

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the clock() function. Is that a UNIX function?

Terminal has a man page for a clock function but it says that it reports the processor time used in the current process.

I would suggest using the NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate function instead. That gives a value in seconds and decimal fractions of a second:

> var startTime: NSTimeInterval
>
> startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
>   myLongRunningFunction() let secondsToRun =
>   NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - startTime
>
> print(format: "function took %.5f seconds to run", secondsToRun)

Where your result will be expressed in floating-point seconds.